# Some of "Services" menu is in Portuguese

Tags: snow-leopard, services

I tend to assign keyboard shortcuts to the services I use most often. Occasionally, I need to access one from the toolbar menu. When I dropped the menu down today, I noticed that some of the items were in Spanish. All of the aforementioned items seemed to be the core services - ones I had installed or built myself are still in English.
No idea how this happened. Please see the screenshot below.
[image: Some Spanish, some English.]

Running 10.6.8 on a late 08 MBP. 
Cheers

Comment: FWIW, it looks like the menu items are in Portuguese, not Spanish. Not that that solves your problem or anything.

Comment: Good call. I noticed right after I posted that some of the words weren't quite right - not that I'm any good in Spanish or Portuguese :) Post title updated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common fix for this problem is to go to system preferences/language & text/language and use the Edit button to uncheck the box for the offending language and restart.

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems unclear why did that happen (perhaps you've got some permission issues?), you could delete the Portuguese language package from your System with [Monolingual](http://monolingual.sourceforge.net/), and that should do the trick.